# SQL joins returning multiple results

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
select 
tmp.templatedesc Template
,sec.name Section
,q.questiontext Questions,
--,sum(case when q.responserequired = '0' then 1 else  null end)  as 'N/A'
--,sum(case when q.responserequired = '1' then 1 else  null end)  as Scored
--,count (case when (qr.weightedscore is not null and tmp.templatedesc  = 'QA 30 Day Call Form' and
--sec.name = 'opening' and
--rv.reviewstatusid = 1 )then 1 else null end) as scored
----,(case when qr.weightedscore <> q.weight then rv.reviewid else null end) as fail
--count (case when qr.weightedscore is null then 1 else null end) NA,
--count (case when qr.weightedscore is not null then 1 else null end) scored, 






 sec.sequencenumber, q.questionnumber, qr.*



from 
aqm.dbo.reviewtemplate tmp (nolock)

inner join aqm.dbo.section sec on sec.templateid =tmp.templateid 
inner join aqm.dbo.sectionresult scr on scr.sectionid = sec.sectionid
inner join aqm.dbo.questionresult qr on qr.sectionresultid = scr.sectionresultid
inner join aqm.dbo.question q on q.questionid = qr.questionid
--inner join aqm.dbo.questiontype qt on qt.questiontypeid = q.questiontypeid
--left outer join aqm.dbo.questionoption qo on qo.questionid = q.questionid
inner join aqm.dbo.review rv on tmp.templateid = rv.templateid
inner join aqm.dbo.media md on md.mediaid = rv.mediaid
inner join  aqm.dbo.iqmuser ut on md.userid = ut.userid

where 
rv.reviewstatusid = 1 and 
tmp.templatedesc  = 'QA 30 Day Call Form' 
and sec.name = 'opening' and
convert(varchar,dateadd(hh,-7,rv.reviewdate), 101) = '07/07/2014'
and ut.windowslogonaccount = 'name.name'
and q.questionnumber = 4

--group by 
--tmp.templatedesc , sec.name, q.questiontext, sec.sequencenumber, q.questionnumber

order by 
sec.sequencenumber, q.questionnumber
```

the questionresultid and sectionresultid are returning multiple values

[image]

how can i fix the joins so that it doesnt return multiple values?

i have it drilled down to a date and a person so that it should only return one row of results( but that obviously didnt work)

not sure what other data i can provide

***update***

i think it has to do with joins

inner join aqm.dbo.sectionresult scr on scr.sectionid = sec.sectionid
    inner join aqm.dbo.questionresult qr on qr.sectionresultid = scr.sectionresultid

as those are the ones returning multiple results.

just dont know how to fix it

Comment: Just imagine that someone else asked you this question.  Would you be able to understand it?  What questions would you ask to clarify the situation?  What additional information would you need? After these considerations please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: thanks, sorry brain is fried ...ill adjust in a bit, i drilled down a bit

Comment: The way you're comparing `rv.reviewdate` will cause the system to ignore indices.  Subtract 7 days from the constant value, and if the actual type is a timestamp, you need to query it as a range - [use an inclusive lower-bound, exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  When dealing with `JOIN`s, always put as many conditions as possible as part of the `ON` clauses.  Your problem is coming because, of course, you have multiple source rows (which may also give incorrect results).  Give us samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, neither aqm.dbo.questiontype nor aqm.dbo.questionoption are used in your return fields or your where clause so get rid of them if they aren't required.

Second, you are OUTER JOINing on the aqm.dbo.review, but the reviewstatusid and reviewdate are required in the WHERE clause - so this should probably be an INNER JOIN.

Last, best way to debug issues like this is to comment out the COUNT statements and the GROUP BY clause - and see what raw data is being returned.

Comment: i ended up drilling down and can see where issues are happening i just dont know how to fix it yet...will update in a bit